# Get input field values and put them into a 2D array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get input field values and put them into a two dimensional array. But the problem is am not able to put the values into their desired location.  for instance get n number of values entered, and then put them into nXn array.

Here's the html inputs fields

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="number" id="0" name="R0C0" placeholder="R0C0" ></td>
     <td><input type="number"  id="1" name="R0C1" placeholder="R0C1" ></td>
     <td><input type="number"  id="2" name="R0C2" placeholder="R0C2" ></td>
     <td><input type="number"  id="3" name="R0C3" placeholder="R0C3" ></td>
     <td><input type="number"  id="4" name="R0C4" placeholder="R0C4" ></td>
     <td><input type="number"   id="5"name="R0C5" placeholder="R0C5" ></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td><input type="number" id="6" name="R1C0" placeholder="R1C0" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="7" name="R1C1" placeholder="R1C1" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="8" name="R1C2" placeholder="R1C2" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="9" name="R1C3" placeholder="R1C3" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="10" name="R1C4" placeholder="R1C4" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="11" name="R1C5" placeholder="R1C5" ></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td><input type="number" id="12" name="R2C0" placeholder="R2C0" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="13" name="R2C1" placeholder="R2C1" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="14" name="R2C2" placeholder="R2C2" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="15" name="R2C3" placeholder="R2C3" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="16" name="R2C4" placeholder="R2C4" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="17" name="R2C5" placeholder="R2C5" ></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td><input type="number" id="18" name="R3C0" placeholder="R3C0" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="19" name="R3C1" placeholder="R3C1" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="20" name="R3C2" placeholder="R3C2" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="21" name="R3C3" placeholder="R3C3" ></td>
     <td><input type="number"id="22"  name="R3C4" placeholder="R3C4" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="23" name="R3C5" placeholder="R3C5" ></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td><input type="number" id="24" name="R4C0" placeholder="R4C0" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="25" name="R4C1" placeholder="R4C1" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="26" name="R4C2" placeholder="R4C2" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="27"name="R4C3" placeholder="R4C3" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="28" name="R4C4" placeholder="R4C4" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="29" name="R4C5" placeholder="R4C5" ></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <td><input type="number" id="30" name="R5C0" placeholder="R5C0" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="31" name="R5C1" placeholder="R5C1" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="32" name="R5C2" placeholder="R5C2" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="33" name="R5C3" placeholder="R5C3" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="34" name="R5C4" placeholder="R5C4" ></td>
     <td><input type="number" id="35" name="R5C5" placeholder="R5C5" ></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
<button onClick="checking()">check</button>
```

....with four more rows and ids in increasing order till 36.

javascript code:

```
const checking = () =>{
   //create a 2D array of 6 rows and 6 columns
  var x = new Array(6);
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i] = new Array(6);
  }

    //loop to get all input values ie from id=1 to id=36
    var k=0;
    for(k; k<35; k++){
      //loop for rows
      for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
        var xValues = x[i]; //x[i] reference the array object
        //loop for columns
         for(var j=0; j < xValues.length; j++){
          //put the input values to the 2D array respective position
           x[i][j] =document.getElementById(k).value;
          //console.log("x"+"["+i+"]"+"["+j+"]"+" = "+x[j]);
         }
      }
   }
 }//end function
```

for supposed an input say,

```
x = [
  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  [2,3,4,5,5,6],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  [3,5,4,2,2,2],
  [4,5,3,4,3,2],
  [4,3,2,3,5,3]
];
```

I expect an output of,

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
2,3,4,5,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
3,5,4,2,2,2
4,5,3,4,3,2
4,3,2,3,5,3
```

However, from my script above, I get wired results.
something like this............

```
x[0][0] = 1,,,,, 
x[0][1] = ,,,,, 
x[0][2] = ,,,,, 
x[0][3] = ,,,,, 
x[0][4] = ,,,,, 
x[0][5] = ,,,,, 
x[1][0] = 1,1,1,1,1,1 
x[1][1] = 1,1,,,, 
x[1][2] = ,,,,, 
x[1][3] = ,,,,, 
x[1][4] = ,,,,, 
x[1][5] = ,,,,, 
x[2][0] = 1,1,1,1,1,1 
x[2][1] = 1,1,1,1,1,1
x[2][2] = 1,1,1,,, 
x[2][3] = ,,,,, 
x[2][4] = ,,,,, 
x[2][5] = ,,,,, 
x[3][0] = 1,1,1,1,1,1 
x[3][1] = 1,1,1,1,1,1 
x[3][2] = 1,1,1,1,1,1 
x[3][3] = 1,1,1,1,,
x[3][4] = ,,,,,
....................
```

Comment: Don't even bother with array size constructor. Just initialize the literal `[]` and `push` values in, or assign to indices as necessary. PS you should describe the results you do get.

Comment: Do you want to assign values to each input according to that 2D array? Or did you want to extract values from all inputs to create a 2D array? I'm assuming former since the HTML doesn't have any values.

Comment: @zer00ne yes! I want to assign as per the 2D array. The html inputs have exactly the same number size as the array.  The html values will come through filling the input fields.

Comment: Is the first `<tr>` missing by accident, or is it the same in your HTML?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I  missed it, but the problem is in js code. see updated sample code to reflect whats in my editor

Comment: @tehhowch see updates. the push method won't work appropriately with 2D array

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code doesn't work is due to the most outer loop.

```
for(var k = 0; k<35; k++){
  for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    var xValues = x[i]; //x[i] reference the array object
    for(var j=0; j < xValues.length; j++){
      x[i][j] =document.getElementById(k).value;
    }
  }
}
```

This loops for every element over all the rows and cells (36 ∙ 6 ∙ 6 = 1296 iterations). You have to choose your loop. You can go with either the most outer, or the inner two.

```
for (let k = 0; k < 36; k++) {
  let i = Math.floor(k / 6),
      j = k % 6;

  x[i][j] = document.getElementById(k).value;
}
```

or

```
for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
    let k = i * 6 + j;

    x[i][j] = document.getElementById(k).value;
  }
}
```

But not both nested in each other.

I've also added a working example.

```js
function checking1() {
  var x = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < 36; index++) {
    // don't forget to change ^ from 35 to 36 or < to <=
    let innerIndex = index % 6,
        outerIndex = Math.floor(index / 6);
  
    if (!innerIndex) {
      x[outerIndex] = [];
    }
    
    let element = document.getElementById(index);
    x[outerIndex][innerIndex] = element.value;
  }
  
  console.log("checking1", x);
}

function checking2() {
  var x = new Array(6).fill().map((_, outerIndex) => {
    return new Array(6).fill().map((_, innerIndex) => {
      var index = outerIndex * 6 + innerIndex,
          element = document.getElementById(index);
      return element.value;
    });
  });
  
  console.log("checking2", x);
}

var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", checking1);
button.addEventListener("click", checking2);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="0" name="R0C0" placeholder="R0C0" ></td>
    <td><input type="number"  id="1" name="R0C1" placeholder="R0C1" ></td>
    <td><input type="number"  id="2" name="R0C2" placeholder="R0C2" ></td>
    <td><input type="number"  id="3" name="R0C3" placeholder="R0C3" ></td>
    <td><input type="number"  id="4" name="R0C4" placeholder="R0C4" ></td>
    <td><input type="number"   id="5"name="R0C5" placeholder="R0C5" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="6" name="R1C0" placeholder="R1C0" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="7" name="R1C1" placeholder="R1C1" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="8" name="R1C2" placeholder="R1C2" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="9" name="R1C3" placeholder="R1C3" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="10" name="R1C4" placeholder="R1C4" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="11" name="R1C5" placeholder="R1C5" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="12" name="R2C0" placeholder="R2C0" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="13" name="R2C1" placeholder="R2C1" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="14" name="R2C2" placeholder="R2C2" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="15" name="R2C3" placeholder="R2C3" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="16" name="R2C4" placeholder="R2C4" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="17" name="R2C5" placeholder="R2C5" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="18" name="R3C0" placeholder="R3C0" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="19" name="R3C1" placeholder="R3C1" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="20" name="R3C2" placeholder="R3C2" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="21" name="R3C3" placeholder="R3C3" ></td>
    <td><input type="number"id="22"  name="R3C4" placeholder="R3C4" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="23" name="R3C5" placeholder="R3C5" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="24" name="R4C0" placeholder="R4C0" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="25" name="R4C1" placeholder="R4C1" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="26" name="R4C2" placeholder="R4C2" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="27"name="R4C3" placeholder="R4C3" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="28" name="R4C4" placeholder="R4C4" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="29" name="R4C5" placeholder="R4C5" ></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="30" name="R5C0" placeholder="R5C0" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="31" name="R5C1" placeholder="R5C1" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="32" name="R5C2" placeholder="R5C2" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="33" name="R5C3" placeholder="R5C3" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="34" name="R5C4" placeholder="R5C4" ></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="35" name="R5C5" placeholder="R5C5" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking just logging the data, this will suffice:

```js
checking = () => {
  let res = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).reduce((acc, input) => {
    // Determining the indexes based off of your input name attributes
    let indexes = input.name.match(/R([0-9]+)C([0-9]+)/);
    // Ensure that the returned array length of the regular expression above is 3
    if (indexes.length === 3) {
      if (acc[indexes[1]] === undefined) {
        acc[indexes[1]] = {};
      }
      acc[indexes[1]][indexes[2]] = input.value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="0" name="R0C0" placeholder="R0C0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="1" name="R0C1" placeholder="R0C1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="2" name="R0C2" placeholder="R0C2"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="3" name="R0C3" placeholder="R0C3"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="4" name="R0C4" placeholder="R0C4"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="5" name="R0C5" placeholder="R0C5"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" id="6" name="R1C0" placeholder="R1C0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="7" name="R1C1" placeholder="R1C1"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="8" name="R1C2" placeholder="R1C2"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="9" name="R1C3" placeholder="R1C3"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="10" name="R1C4" placeholder="R1C4"></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="11" name="R1C5" placeholder="R1C5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="checking()">check</button>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: actually this works for 1D array scenario and I think its similar to using push .But not in my case. see my question with updated sample code

Comment: @Kose, I've updated my answer. The item placement is now based off of the names of your inputs, i felt that that was the most intuitive :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the natural structure of the table to provide the array dimensions, that way you won't get errors if they code ever gets out of sync with the html. Maybe something along these lines:

```
const checking = () => {
    const result = [];
    const rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('tr'));

    rows.forEach(row => {
      var current = [];
      const inputs = Array.from(row.getElementsByTagName('input'));

      inputs.forEach((input) => {
        current.push(input.value);
      });
      result.push(current);
    });

    result.forEach(val => {
      console.log("[" + val.toString() + "]");
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid writing tedious HTML -- create your table and inputs dynamically. While generating the HTML assign values to inputs as they are being created. The `Map()` object will be useful on the next phase of your project.

**DOM Methods**
- [**HTMLFormElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)
- [**.insertRow()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) & [**.insertCell()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)
- [**.insertAdjacentHTML()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
**Data Structures** - Array & [Map](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html)

```js
let data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [3, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2],
  [4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2],
  [4, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3]
];

let matrix = new Map();

function setData(data, matrix, rows = 6, cells = 6) {
  const form = document.forms[0];
  const seats = document.querySelector('.seats');
  
  for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    const row = seats.insertRow();
    for (let c = 0; c < cells; c++) {
      const cel = row.insertCell();
      const input = `<input id="r${r}c${c}" name="r${r}c${c}" class="seat" type="number" min="0" max="6" value="0">`;
      cel.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', input);
      cel.className = `r${r}c${c}`;
      matrix.set(`r${r}c${c}`, data[r][c]);
      form[`r${r}c${c}`].value = data[r][c];
    }
  }
}

setData(data, matrix)
```

```css
table {
  display: inline-table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 80%
}

.concertHall {
  width: 80%;
}

th {
  width: 5ch;
  height: 1.2rem;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.seats td::before {
  content: attr(class)' ';
}

.seat {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4ch;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.rowIdx {
  width: 10px;
  transform:translate(12px, 0px);
  font-weight: 900;
}

.rowIdx td {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form id='seating'>
  <fieldset name='layout'>
    <legend>Seating Matrix</legend>
 <table class='rowIdx'><thead><tr><th>&nbsp;</th></tr><tr><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>6</td></tr></tbody></table><table class='concertHall'><thead class='colIdx'><tr><th colspan='6'>Front Stage</th></tr><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th></tr></thead><tbody class='seats'></tbody></table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```